# Как обернуть весь класс в throws?

Tags: java, android

Как обернуть весь класс в `throws`?

Просто у меня в классе много методов и в каждой я делаю `try catch`, код становиться здоровым и не читабельным.

Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы `try catch` был только там, где я создаю объект класса.

Типа

```
try{ new MyClas() }
```

В Java не силен, сильно не ругайтесь

Comment: Так передавайте исключение выше.

Comment: Действительно проще передавать исключение выше, а уже там для каждого типа исключения написать свой блок `catch`

Comment: Дак не работает. По логике так и должно работать.
В Android Studio весь код красным становиться.

Comment: Может вы не поняли. Попробуйте убрать все ваши try catch блоки внутри класса, добавьте в сигнатуру  методо throws. А ловите данные исключения там, где вызываете непосредственно данные методы(т.е. в других классах)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Укажите вашему конструктору, что он может выкинуть исключение:

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() throws Exception { }

}
```

Теперь его можно создавать только в блоке try

```
 try{ new MyClas(); } catch(Exception e) {}
```

Все остальные методы также можно сопроводить throws Exception и оборачивать их вызовы в try - так вам не надо будет внутри самих методов писать try блоки

Comment: А throws мне для каждого метода в классе надо сделать чтоли? 
Нельзя чтобы для всего класса указать и все?

Comment: @xTIGRx, да, надо для каждого метода. Нет, для всего класса указать нельзя

Comment: Вообще, выкидывать исключение в конструкторе не рекомендуется http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html (Guideline 7-3 / OBJECT-3:). Но как правило, в приложениях, где безопасность ставится на второй план, мало кто заморачивается.

Answer (score 8):

Есть несколько вариантов, если не хотите оборачивать вызовы метода в `try catch` блок

1. переписать реализацию методов, и бросать из них только проверяемые исключения `RuntimeException`.
2. воспользоваться библиотекой [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows.html), а именно аннотацией `@SneakyThrows`
3. сделать обертку декоратор для вашего класса, где в методах будут блоки обработки исключений, и делегирование вызова исходному методу
4. прокидывать исключения выше, добавляя в сигнатуру метода `throws Exception`

Comment: Просто раньше в Android Studio была команда чтобы добавить исключение throws в класс. Теперь нету.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в этом классе переопределяются методы, которые не должны кидать исключения и поэтому приходиться эти исключения обрабатывать в секциях try-catch внутри методов? В этом случае, как было сказано выше лучше использовать делегирование и паттерн Декоратор.